# Automatically return when reaching end of text field

Tags: ios, textfield

I have created a text field on my storyboard. When running the app and entering text into the text field, it doesn't automatically return when I reach the edge of the text box. It just continues typing past the edge of the text field.

Is there a way that I can make it automatically return when I reach the edge of the text field?

Comment: UITextField is really only design to be a single line. You can make it into multiple lines but it would be much more simple to use UITextView for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat textWidth = [textfield.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textfield.font}].width;
CGFloat frameWidth = textfield.frame.size.width;
if(textWidth > frameWidth) {
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Hi moby, Thanks for the reply. Where is it that I put this code?

Comment: You can put it in the textfield's delegate method: `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;`